# How I can use ICC profiles with Google Print Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-print, color-profile, color-management

I'm trying to print photos through GCP. All works, but what about icc profiles? How I can use it

Answer (score 0):

In the Cloud Job Ticket (CJT), there is the `vendor_ticket_item` item. According to Google Cloud Print documentation, printer manufacturers may use it to set **vendor-specific capabilities**. It accepts a JSON array of key-value pairs.

In addition, printers may use the `vendor_capability` CDD item to expose to the cloud (and therefore applications) its vendor-specific attributes, so apps can be noticed of them.

[vendor-ticket-item documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#VendorTicketItem)

The real thing is that, based on my limited experience with Google Cloud Print, printer manufacturers don't use to support any vendor-specific attributes.

However, in order to work with vendor-specific attributes (for example, ICC profiles):

1. Printer must be prepared to support and understand specific `vendor_ticket_item` values. If you are a printer manufacturer, you may promote it.
2. Client must set the job with the proper `vendor_ticket_item` id and value. Later, printer must read it (for example, a specific ICC profile) in order to apply it to the job.

But, as I said previously, it is very rare that your printer supports what you want to achieve.